# How to develop Reusable Bootstrap-like Components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend, react-bootstrap, es6-modules

React bootstrap and other similar bootstrap libraries provide something like

```js
import Modal from '...';
```

whereas `Modal` can be unpacked further into:

```js
const { Header, Title, Description } = Modal;
```

Although `Modal` itself is a wrapper component.

Sample of their use-case is as such:

```js
<Modal someProps={someValues}>
  <Modal.Title>Some Title</Modal.Title>
  <Modal.Content>Some Content</Modal.Content>
</Modal>
```

How does one develop something like that?

My initial thought was something like this:

```js
const Title = ({children}) => (<something>{children}</something>);

const Content = ({children}) => (<something>{children}</something>);

export {
  Title,
  Content,
};

====================

import Modal from '...';
--or--
import { Title, Content } from '...';
```

but this method will cause `Modal` to not be usable by itself. How does this work? Does anyone have an example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make like that with this approach:

```js
export const Modal = ({children}) => {
 return(
  <div class="modal">{children}</div>
 )
}

export const Title = ({children}) => {
 return(
  <div class="title">{children}</div>
 )
}

export const Content = ({children}) => {
 return(
  <div class="content">{children}</div>
 )
}

// join into single object
var _default = Object.assign(Modal, {
 Title,
 Content
});

export default _default;
```

**We have done** 
Now you can use this component in both (single / separate import)

```js
import Modal from '...';
--or--
import { Modal, Title, Content } from '...';
```

```js
<Modal someProps={someValues}>
  <Modal.Title>Modal Title</Modal.Title>
  <Modal.Content>Some Content</Modal.Content>
</Modal>
--or--
<Modal someProps={someValues}>
  <Title>Modal Title</Title>
  <Content>Some Content</Content>
</Modal>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I'm looking for. I like the usage of `_default` variable! Would have never thought of that previously.

Comment: Btw, you can use variable in any name instead of _default. This is only a convention.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a little bit tricky but here I am.

Layout.js

```
import "./layout.css";

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return <section>{children}</section>;
};

Layout.Header = ({ children }) => <header>{children}</header>;

Layout.Body = ({ children }) => <main>{children}</main>;

Layout.Footer = ({ children }) => <footer>{children}</footer>;

export default Layout;
```

App.js

```
import Layout from "./Layout";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Layout>
        <Layout.Header>Header goes here</Layout.Header>
        <Layout.Body>Body goes here</Layout.Body>
        <Layout.Footer>Footer goes here</Layout.Footer>
      </Layout>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your example doesn't allow for
```
<Components>
  <Components.Title />
  ...
</Components>
```

I want something that can also use the `Components` and put the `Title` and `Content` in the right placing accordingly

Comment: Yeah, you are right it's not a complete solution I'll try to get back to you on it!

Comment: @AndreHadianto check out now.